# Using Svelte, how can I prevent more than one character from displaying in an input element

Tags: typescript, svelte

I'm new to Svelte, and I'm trying to implement something I've done successfully in React. I'm making a game like Wordle or a crossword puzzle in which I have several inputs, one after another, and I want only one character to display in each input. If I enter "AB", I want only "B" to display. If I type very quickly, "asdf", I want only "F" to display.

I'm attempting to handle this with binding and an onInput handler, and it works partially. That is, I can type into the cells and my text displays. If I log the values in the store, they are as I'd expect — the store gets updated when I type into the input element and the input elements display the values that come from store.

However, when I add additional logic to my input handler to store only the last letter,  I'm able to get more than one character to display at a time. I'd love any suggestions to fix this.

Here's relevant code:

**Store**

```
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
  
    type Cell = {
        value: string;
        id: string;
        index: number;
    }

    type Grid = {
        cellMap: Record<string, Cell>;
        cellsArray: Array<Cell>
    }

    const grid:Grid = {... // a bunch of data}

    const puzzleStore = writable<Grid>(grid);
```

**+page.svelte**

```html
    <script>
        import { onDestroy, onMount } from 'svelte';
        import PuzzleStore from '../../../stores/PuzzleStore';

        export let storeGrid;

        export let data;

        $: ({ puzzle } = data); // data comes from +page.server.js

        onMount(() => {
            if (puzzle) {
                PuzzleStore.set(puzzle.grid);
            }
        });

        const unsubscribe = PuzzleStore.subscribe((current) => {
            if (current) {
                storeGrid = current;
            }
        });

        onDestroy(() => {
            unsubscribe();
        });
    </script>

    <!-- pass GameParent a grid prop that is the dynamic storeGrid or the server-rendered data if hydration hasn't yet occured -->
    {#if storeGrid || puzzle.grid}
        <GameParent grid={storeGrid || puzzle.grid} />
    {/if}
```

**GameParent component**

```html
    <script>
        import PuzzleStore from '../../stores/PuzzleStore';

        export let grid;

        export function updateStore(cell) {
   
     // cell is an object like this: { id: "Some ID", value: "Some Value" }
        grid.cellMap[cell.id] = cell;
        grid.cellsArray[cell.index] = cell;
        PuzzleS

        PuzzleStore.set(grid);
    }
    </script>

    {#each grid.cellsArray as cell}
        <CellContainer
            {cell}
            {updateStore}
        />
    {/each}
```

**CellContainer**

```html
    <script>
        export let cell;
        export let updateStore; 

        export function handleInput(event) {
            let value = event.target.value.trim().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
            cell.value = value;
            updateStore(cell);
        }
    </script>

    {#if cell}
        <Cell
          value={cell.value}
          onInput={handleInput}
        />
    {:else}
        <!-- DeadCell is a non-interactive black square -->
        <DeadCell />
    {/if}
```

**Cell**

```html
    <script>
        export let value;
        export let onInput;
    </script>

    <input
        type="text"
        on:input={handleInput}
        bind:value
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the problem might be here:

```html
<input
  type="text"
  on:input={handleInput}
  bind:value
/>
```

When you use `bind:value`, then when you enter something in the `<input>` element, Svelte will update the variable `value` with whichever text the user has entered in the `<input>` element when that text changes. However, your `handleInput` function will also be called when this happen, and it changes the value in the store, so there will be a race between the store and `bind` to update what value that should be in the `<input>` element. Races like this are never good and can lead to unpredictable behaviors, so you should try to avoid that.

Since the `<input>` element get its value from the store and `handleInput` updates the store when the entered text changes, you probably don't need the `bind` directive at all, and can instead simply use:

```html
<input
  type="text"
  on:input={handleInput}
  {value}
/>
```

Not sure if this change alone will fix your problem, but you can start by testing it.

Comment: I like that suggestion but it doesn't seem to fix it; it still displays multiple characters in the input

Comment: Show the code for how you're using the "Parent Component", especially how the prop `grid` is assigned its value.

Comment: Sure thing, I just added a bit more code in +page.server.js

Comment: It should be enough to use `<GameParent grid={$PuzzleStore} />`; you shouldn't need to use the `storeGrid` variable at all. Don't think that will solve your problem, but it will make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution that involves using the element's maxlength attribute:

```
<input 
  type="text  
  maxlength="1" 
  {value} 
  on:input={handleInput}
  on:keydown={handleKeydown}
/>
```

This prevents user from entering more than a single character, but it also prevents them from changing to a different character without manually deleting the existing one first. I can handle that by deleting the value on keydown:

```
function handleKeydown(event) {
    // let user tab through inputs without deleting what's there
    if (event.code.toUpperCase() !== 'TAB') {
        event.target.value = '';
    }
}
```

I don't know that this is an optimal solution so I'll keep exploring.